# Mount an smb share with fstab vs sudo mount... problems

Tags: ubuntu, samba, fstab, cifs

This works in the terminal.. `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=pass //10.100.136.4/bus /media/bus`

This does not work in fstab on boot.. `//10.100.136.4/bus  /media/bus  cifs  username=user,password=pass,_netdev  0  0`

What am I doing wrong? I need this to automatically mount this share on boot.
I can run sudo mount -a and mount the drive manually after boot, so I thought maybe the _netdev is not delaying properly? I have set a static IP in the network manager but have not tried in /etc/network/interfaces yet, that shouldn't make a difference but??

cfis-utils is installed.

Another odd thing is when I connect to the share in Gnome>Files>Connect to Server with the same creds, I get rw access to the share. But when using the mount command, I only have read permission. Same when I connect to the share in Windows, read and write. This really isn't an issue as even though I cannot write to the share, the application that I need to backup to the share can!?
I would really like to understand that.

The share is on another ubuntu desktop. I created a new linux user "user", a new group, assigned that user to the group, set permissions.. pretty much followed this tut..https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/system-config-samba-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

You may try to wait a little. Change to your specs and add to /etc/rc.local:

```
(
until ping -nq -c3 10.100.136.4; do
   # Waiting for network
   sleep 1
done
mount -t cifs -o vers=1.0,credentials=/home/<user>/<creds_file>,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,_netdev //10.100.136.4/bus /media/bus 2> /home/<user>/mounterr.log
)&
```

Sure you may left the direct user/password in the command, but to have the special file with creds may be more convenient. The format of the file is

```
user=<user>
password=<password>
```

There may be some unexpected nuances. For example, I had to add "vers=1.0" whith the Linux Mint 18.3, while it was not necessary in 18.1.

Comment: Yes, that would certainly work... as a workaround, but it should not be this hard to mount at boot but appears it may be. I had not seen this post when i asked the question here but it seems very similar with similar suggestions to yours. [https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/delay-mount-947028/]

Comment: Sure I've found it somewhere, but lost the link (your link in wrong, BTW). And I don't see why does it seem hard at all. At least to try.

Comment: LoL, can't even get a link right... it is https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/delay-mount-947028/

I ended up using AutoFS... which is what i should have used to begin with.